# Yosemite psql only

Tags: macos, postgresql, command-line, psql, osx-yosemite

I have done a fresh install of Yosemite. I have read that PostgreSQL is the default database in MacOS now. The problem is that I can't find psql in this new installation. It looks like either I missed to check to install database server or it is not available in Yosemite by default.

I have tried to find the file using: find . | grep psql

The PostgreSQL server is running on remote machine, so, basically I only need command line utility to connect to the remote server

My question is: how can I install just psql (command line utils) without installing the whole server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OS X built-in PostgreSQL is for system data, not for user](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/ware-yosemite-possible-postgresql-upgrade-issues-os-x-10-10/). Please use Homebrew, Macports, Postgres.app or the EDB installer instead.

It's data directory is for example deleted on upgrade.

Comment: It's also been hidden on Yosemite, finally. So you can't use it without a bunch of effort, and you should not use it anyway.